# Can Unity games share "MonoBleedingEdge", UnityPlayer.dll and UnityCrashHandler32.exe

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a game launcher in Unity. Launcher will able to open games which are in a folder like "<launcher_path>/Games/.". But i want to simplify the games. All the games folders will only have "Game_Data" and "Game.exe". Other things like "MonoBleedingEdge", UnityPlayer.dll and UnityCrashHandler32.exe will share between games. Can i do that? Is it possible? Im using Unity 2020.3.5f1